# How to force use of a normal 's' and how to suppress ligatures when using Gothic font?

Tags: fonts, ligatures

I want to use a gothic font for some headings, but the 's' character looks more like a 'f' which makes it really hard to read at times. I know it's *meant* to look like that, but according to the Font Catalogue there should also be a normal 's' available.

But how do I force use of that 's' instead of the 'f'-looking 's'?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}
\gothfamily
The quick fox jumps over the sleazy dog
\end{document}
```

[image]

But here's how it looks in the Font Catalogue (notice the 's' in 'jumps'):

[image]

Also, is there a way of preventing ligatures? I would like 'dog' to be written as 'd og' since it's a bit hard to read otherwise.

Comment: You get the “short s” with `s:`; a ligature can be prevented by putting `\/` between the two letters.

Comment: @egreg Best way to prevent a ligature is `\kern0pt`, no?

Comment: @JosephWright Not necessarily; I prefer `\/`, but in some cases `\kern0pt` might be better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There is a ligature `do` defined in the font; also one for `he`.

Comment: @JosephWright Upon examination of the TFM file, in this case `\/` is the same as `kern0pt`, because no italic correction is defined in the font.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The gothic font by Yiannis Haralambous is meant to reproduce old German typography, which sported several ligatures. The problem of choosing between a long and a short s is quite difficult to solve automatically, because it's not simply context depending, but knowledge of word fragments is necessary when compound words are involved.

So the method for choosing between the two variants is manual: type `s` for a “long s” and `s:` for a short one.

If you need to avoid a ligature, add `\/` between the letters (this will hinder hyphenation, though).

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}

\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}
\gothfamily
The quick fox jumps: over the sleazy d\/og
\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the situation, `\kern0pt` might be better than `\/` (which adds the italic correction). For the `ygoth` font the problem is irrelevant, because only the en-dash and em-dash have a nonzero italic correction.

Just for information. The font defines ligatures for the pairs or triples

(short s)(long s) (short s)t (short s)(short s) (short s)(short s)i
ae
be ba bo
ch ck ct
da de do
ha he ho
ij
ff fi fl ffi ffl
ll
pa pe po pp
qq qz
(long s)(long s) (long s)t (long s)z
oe
tz
va ve vu

The other ligatures are

`s:` for the short s
`"a` `"e` `"o` `"u` for the vowels with umlaut
`"s` for the es-zet

[image]

Here's the test document:

```
\documentclass[border=8,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}
\gothfamily

s:s s:t s:s s:si\par
ae\par
be ba bo\par 
ch ck ct\par
da de do\par
ha he ho ij\par
ff fi fl ffi ffl\par
ll\par
pa pe po pp\par
qq qz\par
ss st sz\par
oe\par
tz\par
va ve vu\par
"a "e "o "u "s

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it safe to use `\/` even between characters that would normally not cause a ligature? If so then I can just automatically insert it between every character.

Comment: @gablin If you don't need hyphenation, yes. But there's a better way also with `pdflatex`, with `microtype`.

Comment: I'm actually using `microtype` in my document, so I'll give the manual a look. Thanks!

Comment: @gablin `\DisableLigatures[a,b,c,d,h,i,l,p,q,t,v]{encoding=LYG}` (you don't want to disable s and f ligatures, I guess).

Comment: useful list.  i'm a bit shaky on whether the short s is required when the first part of a compound ends in s (e.g., los-sagen) but i'm certain that a ligature is *not* appropriate.  presumably `los:\/sagen` would be the proper input?

Comment: @egreg: Since I'm producing my LaTeX document through a Python script, I just inserted a `\/` between every alphabetic character as well as a `:` after every `s`, so I never got around to trying your command with `microtype`. But that might come in handy when I cannot apply the same workaround. =)

Comment: Is it possible to make s produce the short s and ſ (U+017F) the long s? The inverse is easy, of course (`\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017F}{s:}`), but that means the source characters are exactly swapped against the result.

Comment: @lucas.werkmeister I'm afraid this can't work: `s` cannot safely be made into an active character. It could be done if you are willing to type the Fraktur words as the argument to a command.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, is there a way of preventing ligatures?

If you can run LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX, you could make use of the [selnolig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package to suppress ligatures on a document-wide basis. The package was designed mainly to let people suppress ligatures *selectively*. However, it can also be used to suppress ligatures globally. (Full disclosure: I'm the principal author of the `selnolig` package.)

For instance, if you wanted to suppress all `da`, `de`, and `do` ligatures everywhere in a document, you could do so by providing the following statement (after having loaded `selnolig` first, of course):

```
\holig{d[aeo]}{d|a}
```

Here, the character `|` denotes the place where the ligature (or, in this case, any of three ligatures) should be suppress. Note the regex-like syntax, which permits one ligature suppression rule to suppress *three* separate ligatures.

The following screenshot shows two lines of output -- the first with ligature suppression enabled, the second with ligature suppression turned off.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[border=2, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{selnolig} % load package *without* a language option
\nolig{d[aeo]}{d|x} %% set up a ligature suppression rule
\begin{document}
\gothfamily
day den dog

\selnoligoff % turn off selnolig's algorithms

day den dog
\end{document}
```